# ios is it possible to make view over all other applications

Tags: ios, view, window, overlay

Main idea to make notification from background app.
Background app takes coordinates from GPS.
When we found definited coordinates - we draw view over all other programs for some secound.
(Like toast in android).
For example - on top is navigation program, but my window draws at top of them.
I find partial solution iToast - but it doesn't work from background. Only if application active.
Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot show anything out of your application window as your application will be sandboxed by iOS.

Comment: It looks then android is more innovative - because even using toast and own layout you can draw ovrall window with notification.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to notify the user from the background are [Local Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1).

[This discussion about background location updates and local notifications](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/55668-background-location-and-local-notification.html) might help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It may helps me if I can make this notification WITHOUT any buttons, show for user some second and cancel after that. Please say - is it possible or not?

Comment: I'd suggest you to try to find this out from the linked documentation on your own. Learning to understand the docs is crucial for every iOS developer.